# Confusion in example about object slicing in Stroustrup’s book

Tags: c++, object-slicing

In section 17.5.1.4 of [The C++ Programming Language](https://www.stroustrup.com/4th.html), there is the following example:

```
struct Base {
  int b;
  Base(const Base&);
};

struct Derived {
  int d;
  Derived(const Derived&);
};

void naive(Base* p) {
  B b2 = *p;
};

void user() {
  Derived d;
  naive(&d);
  Base bb = d;
};
```

I’ve omitted the comments in the code, and included the apparent typo in `naive()`  (should be `Base b2` ?).

I’m just confused what exactly the issue is here: there is no reason for me to expect a `Derived`  to be copied in either case. I feel as if I ought to be missing something here, but I just cannot understand the point of this “example”.

Can anyone please shed light on this? If this is genuinely an insightful example, I’d like to not be in the dark about it.[image]

Comment: This might not be the best example. I feel like the first time new programmers encounters this problem is when they want to have a `std::vector<Base>` and store `Derived`s in it.

Comment: You are right, there is no "may", slicing always happens in either case. It wouldn't be the first time there's something worded slightly weird, the errata list goes on for a while (I tried to find this specific case, but there are 20+ printings of this book and each has own errata link, so I gave up).

Comment: Thank you for the replies! It’s good to hear that I’m likely not missing anything in this example.

Comment: Or wait, I think I know why it says "may" - the example only calls `naive` with `Derived*`, but it's not required - you can pass `Base*` and then no slicing occurs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the book says "may slice" in `naive`, because if you pass pointer to `Base` in, then slicing will not occur - you will copy `Base` to `Base`. In `user`, you have very clearly a `Derived` object, so the slicing will occur.
In other words, `naive` doesn't know what type is in the pointer, so slicing is only potential (from this function perspective), but `user` knows the type, so slicing is definitive.

I agree that the wording is not very obvious here, but it does make sense when interpreted like this.

Comment: This explains the wording, thank you!